# Numpy for windows 10 64 bit python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I tried installing numpy 1.11.2 on my windows 10 64 bit pc. but I have problem importing it in python(version 2.7 64 bit), what steps should i follow. and if a wheel has to be installed then which verison and how do i install it please?

Comment: Paste the error you're getting when you try to import it.

Comment: If you are new to Python and you are planning to use more libraries than numpy on your Windows 10 machine, I suggest you download Anaconda or other distributions which already contain preinstalled scientific packages, as @NickM has mentioned in the answer.
This is from my personal experience, when I was starting off with Python

Comment: @NickM I'm running into a similar issue. When I try to install Numpy I get: RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.6 required. I looked at the Anaconda site and it's for Python 3.8. How do I get Numpy to install on Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Anaconda distribution which comes with many scientific packages preinstalled from [here](https://www.continuum.io/DOWNLOADS)

I am sure you tried `pip install numpy` , an alternative would be to download numpy wheel from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and do pip install wheel.

Comment: Hi i had downloaded numpy from this site and tried using pip install numpy command on my command prompt in C\:Users\Radhika\Downloads.. I tried following two commands :1) pip install numpy 2)pip install --upgrade pip but it states pip is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: It has to do something with python installation . Could you try using anaconda and let me know what happens ? Also for future reference please state the errors that you are getting, would be easier to decode the problem :)

Comment: @Radhika Great! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem installing Numpy for python 2.7. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
py -2 -mpip install numpy
```

This tells all intrested parties that you really want to install Numpy on python 2.7. It will warn you that you need to upgrade as python 2.7 has come to its end of life.