# Installing NumPy on Python 2.7 for Windows 10

Tags: python, numpy

I need an environment in Windows 10, like this:

conda create --name mariana -c conda-forge python=2.7 scipy=1.2 matplotlib=2.2 pillow=6.2 future=0.18 numba=0.43 pytest=4.6

I wanted to add NumPy 1.10 but I tried unsuccessfully to find NumPy 1.10 here:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy/files?sort=time&version=1.22.2&sort_order=asc&page=3

- I tried with NumPy 1.9, but there are a lot of conflicts with the other packages...

1. which one is the compatible NumPy version in windows?
2. Where can I find it?
3. How should I install it?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514968/numpy-for-windows-10-64-bit-python-2-7

Comment: Thank you @M. Villanueva! Once I tried one of the suggestions in the link you shared I discovered that NumPy was already there!! version: NumPy 1.11.3 
Build: py27hab51878_1207
Channel: conda-forge